# How to insert multiple rows in H2 database with the same IDENTITY() value

Tags: sql, h2

The following SQL produces unexpected results when executed on H2:

```
create table TB_RFD_COUNTRY (
    ID bigint generated by default as identity,
    CREATED_DATE timestamp not null,
    MODIFIED_DATE timestamp,
    ALPHA_CODE_2 varchar(255) not null,
    ALPHA_CODE_3 varchar(255) not null,
    NUMERIC_CODE integer not null,
    primary key (ID)
);

create table TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE (
    ID bigint generated by default as identity,
    CREATED_DATE timestamp not null,
    MODIFIED_DATE timestamp,
    LANGUAGE varchar(2) not null,
    VALUE varchar(255) not null,
    COUNTRY_ID bigint,
    primary key (ID)
);

INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY (ALPHA_CODE_2, ALPHA_CODE_3, NUMERIC_CODE, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('AF', 'AFG', '4', current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE (LANGUAGE, VALUE, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_DATE) VALUES
  ('en', 'Afghanistan', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp),
  ('fr', 'Afghanistan (l'')', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY (ALPHA_CODE_2, ALPHA_CODE_3, NUMERIC_CODE, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('AX', 'ALA', '248', current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE (LANGUAGE, VALUE, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_DATE) VALUES
  ('en', 'Åland Islands', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp),
  ('fr', 'Åland(les Îles)', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY (ALPHA_CODE_2, ALPHA_CODE_3, NUMERIC_CODE, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('AL', 'ALB', '8', current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE (LANGUAGE, VALUE, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_DATE) VALUES
  ('en', 'Albania', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp),
  ('fr', 'Albanie (l'')', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY (ALPHA_CODE_2, ALPHA_CODE_3, NUMERIC_CODE, CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('DZ', 'DZA', '12', current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE (LANGUAGE, VALUE, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED_DATE) VALUES
  ('en', 'Algeria', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp),
  ('fr', 'Algérie (l'')', IDENTITY(), current_timestamp);
```

The first IDENTITY() call returns NULL. The second call returns the ID of the English translation inserted in TB_RFD_COUNTRY_VALUE.

This sort of SQL statements work under MySQL or HSQLDB. Is there a way to make them work under H2 or do I need to store the IDENTITY() result in a variable?

Comment: This does not seem to be H2 SQL's grammar